# HIVE from.unixtime(...) with Time Zone

Tags: hive

I set up my Hive in a machine with GMT+8 time zone. Therefore, `from_unixtime(946656000)` returns `2000-01-01 00:00:00` instead of `1999-12-31 16:30:00`. According to the manual, this function returns the date string using the current system time zone. What can I do to get a date string with UTC time zone i.e. `1999-12-31 16:30:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_utc_timestamp(T timestamp, STRING timezone)`.
Here is an example where a timestamp in IST is converted to UTC.

```
select TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP(from_unixtime(946656000),'IST') c
```

[image]